# Prove commutator identity

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $x$ and $y$ be in $G$. The commutator of $x$ and $y$, denoted  $[x, y]$, is equal to $x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$. Prove  $[x, y] [y, x] =1$

So from the definition given, we get
$$(x^{-1}y^{-1}xy)(y^{-1}x^{-1}yx) =1.$$
I am unsure what operations are legal. Can't we just group the middle $y$ and $y^{-1}$ to get $1$, and so on?

Comment: Yes, that's all there is to it. What makes you unsure that that would be legal?

Comment: The associative law allows you to regroup, or alternatively, to remove parentheses, so as to get the desired cancellations.

Answer (score 1):

What you have done is correct. Specifically, the [associative property](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Group.html) holds true in groups, so you can move parentheses as you see fit. This allows you to write $$(x^{-1}y^{-1}xy)(y^{-1}x^{-1}yx)=x^{-1}y^{-1}x(\underbrace{y\,y^{-1}}_{=1})x^{-1}yx=\cdots=1.$$